# SOM Network (Kohonen's map) in Python - bad effectiveness

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, self-organizing-maps

I've written SOM network for my classes, but it doesn't work and I can't figure out why. I have a Node class, which is single neuron and contains weights vector. Then, I've written SOM class, which contains an array of Node's.

My task is to implement SOM, which from this data: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/SPECT+Heart
show me which input vector (it's a binary vector) fits to which category (0 or 1).

The code: http://pastebin.com/GerkTf3C

The training process:

1. I get at random one input vector from set of training data and category it fits.
2. I actvate the network and get an array of distances, which tells me how the particular neurons are different to input vector.
3. I get indices of winner Node, which has the smalles distance from the input vector.
4. I calculate learning rate and neighbourhood radius for current iteration.
5. For each Node I calculate it's euclidean distance to winner Node.
6. If the Node is in the winner's neighbourhood I calculate how it has to change and update his weight vector and add to it's clusters vector the category it fits.
7. I repeat steps 1 to 6 while learning rate is greater than certain limit
8. Eventually I set up for each Node the category it fits.

Unfortunately I obtain effectiveness about from 40% up to 80% (it's quite unstable and I don't know how to eliminate such randomness) testing it on training set (I assume I should have effectiveness 100% on training set)

P.S. Sorry for my English and quality of code, but I've just started learning Python.

Comment: I did not read your code yet but my first suggestion would be to change the classification algorithm. SOMs are used for unsupervised learning (without classes), and will most likely not perform as good as state-of-art supervised methods such as SVM. If you do like neural networks I would suggest you to read about MLP.

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro thanks for your suggestion, I'm also think that in this case MLP could be better idea, but the other students has to write MPL and I have to make SOM. You're right that SOMs are used for supervised learning, and my SOM should make two clusters (categories) to put input vectors into, but I had no idea how to make SOM to create two clusters.

Comment: SOMs are not used for supervised learning, they are use for UNsupervised learning. Depending on your task it can be possible to separate 2 classes based on SOMs although most times much more complicated than MLP. To explain a little bit more, SOMs tipically use several nodes in the pattern layer to cluster the data therefore not usefull for 2 classes only. Yet you can use the U-matrix to try to get the 2 clusters. However this will still be an unsupervised method. You can of course use the label after training to try to cluster the nodes to each class but that is not efficient.

Comment: If you do need to use SOMs look for variations of the original method that increment the label into the weight update (I know there is something) instead of trying to cluster after the non-supervised training

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro of course I meant UNsupervised learning :) Ok, thanks for your help and time, it's look like I have to do more research in books and articles about SOMs to figure something out. I found something could help me: http://www.smartquant.com/references/NeuralNetworks/neural2.pdf